# Issue with Flutter commands from CI/CD pipelines

Tags: macos, flutter, continuous-integration, flutter-dependencies, azure-pipelines-tasks

Hello recently I upgraded my Mac mini from Mojave to Catalina (10.15.4) for new Xcode. Before updating my CI/CD pipeline used to work fine. My CI/CD pipeline is based on Azure. (I use my Machine as a build machine).

After updating to latest OS version and updating even the XCode. While running the pipeline it fails at "Flutter packages get" step showing this message ##[error]bash: "**/Users/soap/documents/flutter/bin/flutter: Operation not permitted**"

But when i run locally in machine (Navigating to my build agents folder and run these commands) it just work fine.

**Note:**

- I have give the Full Disk permission to Terminal.
- Gave R-W-X permissions to all folders.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant Java with Full Disk Access privileges.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Choose “Security & Privacy”
3. Select the “Privacy” tab, and from the left-side menu select “Full Disk Access”
4. Click the lock icon in the lower left corner and authenticate with an admin level login
5. Click the `+` button to add an application
6. Navigate to `/usr/bin/java`. If you don't see the /usr/ folder, type <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Thanks to that, the “Operation not permitted” error was fix on our side.