# Jenkins with flutter 'flutter clean' is showing 'Operation not permitted'

Tags: macos, flutter, jenkins, continuous-integration

I was trying to do CI with Jenkins for Flutter project on MAC.

I have added the environment variables for HOME, ANDROID_HOME and PATH. But, flutter commands are not working. They are showing 'Operation not permitted'. 
This is exact error:

***bash: /Users/mdhasnain/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: Operation not permitted***

What I have tried so far:
1. Changed admin user's sudo command NOPASSWD and tried flutter command with sudo.
2. Tried to change flutter file's permission in flutter/bin folder: chmod a+x+w+r /Users/username/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter
3. Also tried to change the permission manually.

N.B. flutters commands are working fine from terminal.

I am stuck. Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant Java with Full Disk Access privileges.

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678687/1844385